# Including Hierarchy in Entity Framework Query

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an object hierarchy that looks something like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public virtual List<Page> Pages { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public virtual List<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}
```

I want to load the complete object hierarchy and am going about that like this:

```
Book book = (from b in context.Books.Include("Pages").Include("Paragraphs")
    .Include("Pages.Paragraphs") where CONDITION).SingleOrDefault();
```

I find that `book.Pages` and `book.Paragraphs` are loaded, but `book.Pages[i].Paragraphs` is `null`.

Examining the database, the data looks correct (association columns are all correctly populated).

I also tried the lamda syntax, but do not see how that could work when the parameter is a collection rather than an entity, e.g. one can do something like this:

```
.Include(s => s.Paragraphs.Select(p => p.Id == 1)
```

but I do not see how one could use the lamda syntax to specify that the `Paragraphs` collection for each `Page` in `book.Pages` should be loaded.

Am I missing something, or is this a limitation of Entity Framework?  If it's a limitation, how can I work around it?

Comment: Hmmm, I tried your model myself and had more luck: `book.Pages[i].Paragraphs` has the paragraph I added to it in a previous run.

Comment: Strange.  I simplified the actual problem down a bit to make for a concise question.  I'll re-create the exact question I posed and move forward from there until something breaks.  Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Turns out the `virtual` keyword was missing in the real code.  Thanks again for helping me locate the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the actual code (not the code boiled down for the purpose of asking a targeted question, I was missing a `virtual` keyword.  EF didn't complain about an inability to load the additional data requested through `.Include("Pages.Paragraphs")`, it just silently ignored that request.

```
public class Page
{
    public /* was missing: virtual*/ List<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}
```